# How to convert numeric parameter to text in a MetaPost macro

Tags: macros, metapost

I tried to concatenate some strings in a MetaPost macro where some of them come from numeric parameters. However, I get an error message "Extra tokens will be flushed".

The essence of the problem is in the following snippet:

```
    def foo(expr a) =
      show a; % this prints 1
      show str a; % this prints "" and crashes
    enddef;
    
    show str 1; % this prints "1"
    foo(1);
```

Changing number to string with str works outside macro but not inside the macro. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str' returns the string representation of a suffix, not the numeric value. 1 is the suffix.

- `str 1` is valid (`"1"`) because `1` is a suffix.
- `str -1` is invalid because there is no suffix `-1`

but wait… both `[1]` and `[-1]` are suffixes, `str[1]` renders `"1"` (yes, without `[]`) and `str[-1]` is `[-1]`

The proper function to convert integer or float to string is `decimal`.

It is possible to reimplement `decimal` with `str`, just for fun:

```
% Integer to string without decimal
vardef funny_decimal(expr num) = 
   save s; string s; s=str[num]; % [] needed to evaluate num
   if substring(0,1) of s = "[":
      substring (1,length(s)-1) of s
   else:
      s
   fi
enddef;
```